# Docker dev containers и переменные окружения

Tags: python, docker, .env, pydantic, containers

Изучаю docker dev containers и наткнулся на такую историю, что pydantic 1.10 не позволяет встроенными средствами установить для конфигов приоритет .env файла над переменными окружения (судя по документации https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/settings/#dotenv-env-support, можно написать обработчик, но что-то сложно).
Почему возникла проблема: у меня переменные окружения при запуске контейнера разработки тянутся из .env файла, а внутри контейнера хотелось бы иметь возможность его редактировать).
Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне тут поступить грамотно?